# Problems with Clickable DIV

Tags: html, clickable

I have tried to make a clickable DIV, but I am having problems because not all the DIV (it's a logo) turns into clickable. Only a rectangle of 5px in the top of the logo and another rectangle of 5px in the bottom of the logo are clickable. In the rest of the logo the normal cursor appears, and not the "hand".

Maybe another div is overlaping? I don't know. I have tried with two solutions in javascript an css ([+info](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=223))

But finally I had the same results, only two small parts of the logo can be clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the actual code you are using. At least the interesting part. Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: @Sverker84 thanks, I posted the code. I tried with several browsers but the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a bit like a floating problem. Are you using floats inside of this DIV and have you forgotton to make a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`?

Comment: I tried adding that to the div but I have the same problem. I started using a created joomla template (which use floats) and I am trying to add this clickable logo. You cant check the problem at www.balloncesto.com (logo). Thanks.

Comment: Ehm... okay... Why are you using not an image and wrap it with a simple link?

Comment: Because templates use only CSS and I want to keep the style of the web site. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe this template had just no image logo before? Which is the only reason, they have used DIVs only, yet?

Comment: I took the code for inserting this logo from another template and it works, but I would like to turn it into a link too.

Comment: Finally I solved it, it was a table that was overlaping the logo. The solution was to put the table before the logo in the code, so the image overlaps the table. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.